# Is there any other way to install MongoDB PHP driver?

Tags: php, mongodb, pecl, php-mongodb

I am trying to install MongoDB PHP driver for PHP version 8.2.4

I tried installing from [here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) but available DLL files are not compatible with my PHP version. I installed the latest version available which is 1.17.2 but it does not have php_mongodb.dll.

I also tried installation using pecl but it's not working.

`pecl install mongodb downloading mongodb-1.17.2.tgz ... Starting to download mongodb-1.17.2.tgz (2,064,433 bytes) ......................................................................................................................................................done: 2,064,433 bytes ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php\pear\tests\mongodb\scripts`

Comment: The installer error just looks like a permissions problem. Try running it as an administrator

Comment: Try installing "MongoDB Compass", I think it comes with the driver. (Not sure, wild guess)

Comment: I tried but i get this ERROR: The DSP mongodb.dsp does not exist. I tried looking up and it says i have to install in manually but i can't find dll version in that